# Arangodb CPU Performance differences while running the same application on 2 separate machine

Tags: arangodb

I have a foxx application developed and it is running on machine A. The cpu utilization is usually below 3-4% and sometimes spikes to 20%. I have close to 6 million records.

Same application is deployed on an another machine (exact replica of machine A) and have data of about 100k only, But cpu utilization is at around 200%.

How do I debug this. What is happening on the machine B. Both machines have same application, same arangodb version, same configuration. Disk I/O is also same, memory utilization at machine B is 1/6th of machine A.

Any pointers. This is happening in production enviornment, so its really important for me to debug it quickly.

Comment: First, can you check with the following command which threads in ArangoDB are causing the CPU load: `top -d 1 -p <insert pid of arangod here> -H`. The command might vary from OS to OS, but the `-H` option should show the threads. This should show how much CPU time the threads have accumulated and which ones are the most active.

Comment: `28153 arangodb  20   0 4476996 843480 453348 R 98.8  5.4   1124:44 [scheduler]`
`28154 arangodb  20   0 4476996 843480 453348 R 96.8  5.4   1130:23 [scheduler]`

Comment: So it is almost 100% for each scheduler and there are 2 such scheduler. on machines A however it's in S state. Not sure what scheduler does.

Comment: The scheduler threads are responsible for handling incoming requests and sending data back. They are basically doing the socket I/O. I suspect the system is at 200% because of a *leap second issue* (there seems to have been one at June 30th). Can you try setting the system date on the affected server (e.g. using `sudo date --set ...`)?

Comment: What should be the value of 'date --set ' ?

Comment: The current date, as returned by `date` itself. I cannot paste this without issues in a StackOverflow comment because it will remove the backticks inside backticks, but I'll try: `sudo date --set "``date``"` (the double backticks are wrong, these should be single backticks, but I didn't find a way to get single backticks in a code section of a StackOverflow comment).

Comment: has this helped or is it still the same?

Comment: It looks like it fixed the problem magically. I will monitor the cpu for few more hours and then can be sure.

Comment: It worked for like a day but again cpu utilization is 200% on machine B.

Comment: Still looks like OS/CPU timer issue. If timers expire too early (due to wrong time being reported), everything may fell into a *busy wait* state and consume lots of CPU. You mentioned you have 2 servers. Are these identical in terms of OS version, configuration, virtualization used etc.? Can you also provide information about the OS (distro, version) and, if used, the virtualization setup? Additionally, can you try upgrading the kernel and rebooting the affected instance? If you can't, does another `date --set` help?

Comment: Both machines are Amazone ec2 r3 large instances.ubuntu-trusty-14.04-amd64-server-20150325

Comment: Have you tried upgrading the kernel/OS and rebooting the affected instance? If you can't do this, does another `date --set` help? Is there anything usable in the arangod logs or the syslog before the CPU usage went up?

Comment: Both system has same kernel 3.13.0-48-generic . I tried date --set again but same symptom again after a day of run. No logs.

Comment: Temporarily I am restarting the arangodb app once every day.

Comment: If you encounter the high CPU usage again, could you please do the following then? Capture the pid/thread ids of the *arangod* process once using `top -n 1 -b -H -p $PID > /tmp/arango_pids` (where `$PID` is the process id of *arangod*). And then, while *arangod* is still running, attach for about 30 seconds via strace to see what it is doing internally: `sudo strace -o /tmp/arango_strace -q -tt -T -f -F -s 128 -p $PID`. Note: the latter command may write a big file to `/tmp/arango_strace`, potentially containing sensitive data. However, the two files may help diagnosing the issue further.

Comment: I get the following enteries repetitively:

 http://pastebin.com/FT3e3tw8

Comment: do you see anything useful in the output

Comment: It looks like both of the two scheduler threads call `epoll_wait()` with various file descriptors, and that this syscall returns almost instantly. After that, the events on these descriptors should be handled, but nothing like that is visible. Instead, the event loop restarts and calls `epoll_wait` again. As the events from the file descriptors weren't handled, the syscall again returns almost instantly. All this is happening many times per second, which explains the high CPU usage. The question remains why the file descriptor events aren't handled or removed from the epoll set.

Comment: I am a bit puzzled that the descriptors are still in the epoll set even if obviously their events aren't handled. I tried to reproduce such situation for a few days, with killing connections and clients randomly, but wasn't able to reproduce. To narrow it down a bit, can you provide more info on how you connect to ArangoDB (i.e. which client driver/environment is in use), whether the connections to ArangoDB originate from an external server or localhost, and whether or not you use HTTP keep-alive, and if you've overridden any ArangoDB options, such as `--server.keep-alive-timeout`? Thanks!

Comment: I am also not able to reproduce on machine A (both machines are identical ). I connect arangodb with an external url. I do not use keep-alive and have not changed any of the settings at arangodb server side. If you want I can give you an access to the machine B. my skype is dagarwal82. Thanks a lot !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We were finally able to reproduce such an issue ourselves. We found there was a situation in which a scheduler thread could go into some busy wait state, resulting in the following loop to be executed over and over:

1. a scheduler thread calling `epoll_wait()`
2. `epoll_wait()` returning instantly, signalling an event for a certain file descriptor
3. the correct event handling callback being called, but not removing the file descriptor from the list of watched descriptors
4. goto 1

As the one file descriptor was not properly cleared from the list of watched descriptors, the `epoll_wait()` always signalled an event for the file descriptor to be available. This made it return almost instantly, and the whole above loop being executed many times per second.
This caused CPU spikes in threads named `scheduler`.

We found one reason for this to be a client-side connection timing out while the operation triggered by the connection is still executed on the server-side operation. For example, if a client called a server route that took 5 seconds to complete and respond, but the client disconnected after 3 seconds, then it might have happened.
What made it hard to reproduce it that it did not affect all such client connections, but only some - which ones is still unclear.

This particular issue was fixed in ArangoDB 2.6.5, so you may want to give it a try when it is released.

Comment: Thank you so much. I will try it on 2.6.5 and mark the question answered if it works. Thanks again !

Comment: I know it's a very old post, but it seems we are experiencing something similar on 3.4.1 right now.
31392 arangodb  20   0  635.0g  24.2g  32336 R  38.0  47.3   5016:54 Scheduler

One of the schedulers is stuck and using lots of CPU, that's production.
Similar picture on staging.

Comment: Hi Ivan, it is hard to say what could cause this without any further information. The codebase has changed completely between 2.6.5 and 3.4.1. Do you mind opening an issue in our [Github issue tracker](https://www.github.com/arangodb/arangodb/issues) with as much details as possible, describing the version and deployment in use, the configuration and workload? Thanks!